# How to add view to cardview inside livedata observer

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I am trying to add some radio button into a card view. Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
cardView = findViewById(R.id.card_view);
mGameViewModel.setUpGame().observe(this,this::loadRound);

private void loadRound(List<Smiley> smileys) {
    if (smileys == null) {
        return;
    }
    mAnswersView.loadAnswers(smileys, cardView);
    mGameViewModel.startNewGameRound();
}
```

**AnswerView**

```
public void loadAnswers(List<Smiley> smileys, CardView cardView) {
    if (smileys == null) {
        return;
    }
    removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    for (Smiley smiley : smileys) {
        RadioButton button = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_item, this, false);
        button.setText(smiley.getName());
        button.setTag(R.string.answer_tag, smiley.getCode());
        cardView.addView(button);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any idea please?

EDIT:
The problem here is that the radio button i try to create doesn't show. I've already do some debugging and all of the methods are called until the addView method. But when i take a look on the device, there's no 'extended' view, in this case, radio button at all.

Comment: Pass 'cardView' here instead of 'this' and try: inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_item, cardView, false);

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Explain what's happening. Is it crashing? Or nothing happens on screen? And, add logs or do debug and check whether loadRound is called or not. Check the size of list smileys that's received. Put your layout R.layout.answer_item in a sample activity and check if it looks right.

Comment: i've edited my post thank you

Comment: Check if you use the layout R.layout.answer_item as your activity's layout, if it's showing radio button. If not, the problem is in your layout.

Comment: I don't use it at my activity layout. I try to add specific widget, in this case radiobutton, to my mainactivity layout.

Comment: Try to use the Layout Inspector. Tools -> Layout Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i fixed the problem by using LinearLayout inside the CardView. Then I parse the LinearLayout to the loadAnswer() function, and here's the rest:

```
RadioButton button = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_item, linearLayout, false);
button.setText(smiley.getName());
button.setTag(R.string.answer_tag, smiley.getCode());
linearLayout.addView(button);
```

From this case, I learnt that we can't directly addView to the CardView. You can do it by creating a LinearLayout inside the CardView to add custom widget programmatically inside the CardView.